# Change Search function from String to Integers

Tags: java

This is my function that used to search String (Student Name) inside the text file. But is there any other way to change this function to search integers (Student ID) inside the text file?

```
String STUD_NAME;
System.out.println("ENTER STUDENT NAME: ");
Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
STUD_NAME = name.nextLine();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z]*");

if (name.hasNext(pattern)) {

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("student.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String s;
    String keyword = STUD_NAME;

    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (s.contains(keyword)) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }
} else {
    System.out.println("PLEASE ENTER ALPHABETS NOT NUMBERS/SYMBOLS");
}
```

Comment: That entirely depends on the format of the text file.

Comment: My text file format:

Jones Kevin, 201883, MATH: A, ENG: B

Comment: Step 1: turn your number in to a `String`, Step 2: use the existing code to do a string search.

Comment: Alright, I will check it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code replace "[A-Za-z]*" with "[\d]+"
This will replace your search for a string to search for integers number.
if you know exactly how many numbers is an ID you can use the following:
"[\d]{5}"
and will match an integer of 5 numbers like: 24453

Comment: This JavaDoc page might be helpful :)  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html